# C# SNMP programming

Tags: c#, snmp, mib

I try write some code to retrieve objectID and the result is `2B-06-01-04-01-82-31-01-03-01-01`.
Isn't this value correct?

```
// Send a SysObjectId SNMP request
response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0");
if (response[0] == 0xff)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv[0]);
    return;
}

// Get the community and MIB lengths of the response
commlength = Convert.ToInt16(response[6]);
miblength = Convert.ToInt16(response[23 + commlength]);

// Extract the MIB data from the SNMp response
datatype = Convert.ToInt16(response[24 + commlength + miblength]);
datalength = Convert.ToInt16(response[25 + commlength + miblength]);
datastart = 26 + commlength + miblength;
output= BitConverter.ToString(response, datastart, datalength);
Console.WriteLine("  sysObjectId - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}",
       datatype, output);
```

Does
`conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0")`
mean that it only executes get protocol? How about set?

Comment: Your code formatting is way off (making it very difficult to read) and you're asking way too many questions (some of them are very broad).

Comment: sorry i already edit the question, i just wonder this code isn't it can represent 5 protocol of the SNMPv1 protocl:

Comment: 5 protocols are get-request, get-next-request,set-request, get-response and trap...

Comment: Or #SNMP, http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com

Answer (score 7):

Really if you want to work with SNMP in C# try this assembly [SNMPSharpNet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/). It' very useful.

You will find in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948830/how-to-measure-a-website-bandwidth-uploaddownload-in-mb-using-c-vb-net-progra/5344425#5344425) answer an example of one way (high level) to use it.

But look at the documentation. You can use this assembly in two ways :

1. Low level to create your own SNMP (V1, V2c, V3) PDUs
2. High level, where you just use SNMP

Just try it.

JP