# SNMP-Agent in C#

Tags: c#, snmp

I need to write a VERY basic SNMP Agent in C#, which is able to send traps (V1 or V2) and respond to get (set is not required). 
After long searches, the only suitable solution seems to be SharpSnmp. However, #SNMP's sample agent doesn't work properly and - the bigger issue - it doesn't reply to GET requests.

Is there another possiblity/solution for doings this?

Comment: have you searched for SNMP here? There appears to be lots of questions that have similar questions and answers.

Comment: indeed, but also on this site is everyone referring to #snmp...

Answer (score 2):

Do you try with [snmpsharpnet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/) which is very helpful to play with SNMP on the top of .NET ?

Comment: thanks JP, this looks quite interesting. were you able to handle get requests? currently, I can send them but I need to respond to incoming requests.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it, just have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948830/how-to-measure-a-website-bandwidth-uploaddownload-in-mb-using-c-vb-net-progra/5344425#5344425)

Comment: thanks, this looks promising. however, I do not completely understand your code. Aren't you _sending_ get requests? Sorry if I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @JPBlanc, I think mikeh wants an agent which can respond to SNMP requests. As far as I know snmpsharpnet does not yet have such a feature.

Comment: @LexLi you're right. I'm currently looking with Milan from snmpsharpnet for a solution. If I can figure anything out, I'll let you know.